# Nginx and CSS Issue

Tags: python, css, nginx, uwsgi, corruption

I've set up a local Nginx server with uwsgi for a python website with the following config

```
server {
    root /var/www/localhost/current;
    index index.html index.htm;
    server_name localhost;

    location /static {
        alias /var/www/localhost/current/static;
    }

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/localhost.sock;
        uwsgi_param UWSGI_PYHOME /var/www/localhost;
        uwsgi_param UWSGI_CHDIR /var/www/localhost/current;
        uwsgi_param UWSGI_MODULE wsgi;
        uwsgi_param UWSGI_CALLABLE application;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
       root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    }
}
```

uwsgi config:

```
[uwsgi]
plugins=python
vhost=true
socket=/tmp/localhost.sock
```

When I make changes to my CSS file which is located in the `/static` folder I get the following when I visit it in a browser:

[image: Bad CSS File]

This is what the CSS should look like:

```
body {
    background-color: #002b36;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 50px;
    color: #93a1a1;
}
```

If I remove `color: #93a1a1;` I don't get the `\u0` character. Any idea's on what this could be?

Comment: I know this is silly, but have you tried to delete it and type it without pasting it ?

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady not silly at all and I have, it was the first thing I did.

Comment: the issue looks like it's after `}` did you try to like mark every thing after it and delete it ?

Comment: The CSS file contains only the CSS above and a newline at the end of the file. There is nothing else in it. Might it be a character encoding issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didn't mention above but probably should have. The server is running in VirtualBox.

Thanks to this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/269420/disable-caching-when-serving-static-files-with-nginx-for-development) on serverfault I've added `sendfile off;` to the `/static` configuration which has fixed the issue.

```
location /static {
    alias /var/www/localhost/current/static;
    sendfile off;
}
```

Comment: well this kinda raises a question, without this `sendfile` what is the detected `content-type` for the css file on the browser?

Comment: The `content-type` without `sendfile` in the config was `text/css` and with it is also `text/css`.

Comment: i mean in the browser, like in firebug or some inspector

Comment: That is what I was referring to.

Comment: Thanks for this, was getting the same issue with javascript files.

Comment: Is there a way to solve this without a static location folder and sendfile off. I'm trying to get this to work with send_from_directory().